# How do I solve the Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \newpage ...prevdepth \fi \fi \vfil \penalty -\@M error?

Tags: spacing, output, latex-base, miktex-update, output-routine

I am currently writing my thesis and am using MikTex to do so. I have not updated MikTex in a whole year of time and it was running fine till I did today. Today I updated the MikTex to the latest version and this error started occurring. I would like any help that could be given to me. I am posting a snippet of the code due to which this error has raised.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareCaptionFont{figfont}{\fontsize{9}{\baselineskip}}
\usepackage[font=figfont]{caption}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,calc}
%
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{16}{\baselineskip}\bfseries\flushleft}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\fontsize{14}{\baselineskip}\bfseries\flushleft}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\fontsize{12}{\baselineskip}\bfseries\flushleft}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\title{\textbf{Topic}}
\author{Guru}
\date{}
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\null\mbox{}\vfill}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookd{\vfill\null}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{(\roman{figure})}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{(\roman{table})}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\tikzstyle{process}=[rectangle,rounded corners,text centered,draw=black,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=0.7cm,fill=gray!20,thick, text=red]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick,->,>=stealth]
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\begin{titlingpage}
%\end{titlingpage}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\newpage
%\tableofcontents
%
\newpage
\justifying
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}
%
\section{Abstract}
Text
\newline
\newline
Text
\newline
\newline
\newline
Text
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
```

and it goes on.
The error rises at the \newpage command.

I would be really grateful for any help provided.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it's a problem with `pageslts`

Comment: remove \usepackage{pageslts}

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\flushleft`  (that is part of the `flushleft` environment the commandform is `\raggedright`, and don't use consecutive `\newline` commands, you don't need `\justifying`  justification is the default in latex

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you so much! You are awesome! I can finally carry on with my thesis

Comment: @egreg, thank you so much! On another note, why did this problem arise though?

Comment: Not sure, but I think it's some interaction with other packages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I could use something like ```\bigskip``` maybe then. So not using ```\flushleft``` won't make any difference in the section headers then? Noted the ```\justifying``` suggestion as well. Thank you!

Comment: Pageslts has not been adapted to recent changes in latex.

Comment: use `\raggedright` not \flushleft (\flushleft should never be used as a command in that way)  You must surely  get latex warnings from `\newline\newline` don't ignore warnings!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah okay. Thank you very much for your input! I will implement it the right way then.